# Dragon Naturally Speaking Mac Script with input argument

Tags: applescript

I would like to use  a custom command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking such that while I'm using text Wrangler, and that on my Mac,   trying to go to a specific line For example

```
   {control} + J
   _arg1
   {RETURN}
```

so for example if I were to say  "go to line 10" then my script would execute

```
   {control} + J
   10
   {RETURN}
```

and take me to line 10